# Get Gallery Caption, Image Caption & Gallery Settings When Filtering WP Core Gallery Block

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-hook

When I filter the WP Core Gallery Block like so:

```
add_filter( 'render_block', function( $block_content, $block )
{
    if ( 'core/gallery' === $block['blockName'] )
    {
        var_dump( $block );
    }
}, 10, 2 );
```

I get something like:

```
array(5) {
  ["blockName"]=>
  string(12) "core/gallery"
  ["attrs"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["ids"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(200)
    }
    ["className"]=>
    string(12) "custom-class"
  }
  ["innerBlocks"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["innerHTML"]=>
  string(2630) "[...]"
  ["innerContent"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2630) "[...]"
  }
}
```

What I miss is the image caption and gallery caption:

[image: WP Core Gallery Block]

Also all the other settings (except `className`) are not available:

[image: WP Core Gallery Block]

**So how to access all the settings???**

*Clarification: I'm not after `wp_get_attachment_metadata`!*

Thanks in advance, cheers and a happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

Caption is inside $block['innerHTML'].